# Error al hacer consulta a la tabla pg_user en Redshift

Tags: postgresql

Estoy intentado hacer una consulta a la tabla de usuarios de Redshift, llamada `pg_user` pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

`The field 'valuntil' has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID 702). You can retrieve it as a string by marking it as unknown, please see the FAQ.`

El campo `valuntil` almacena la fecha de expiración de la cuenta de usuario. Estoy utilizando Aginity.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando por la documentación oficial y foros de consulta de Aginity (el software que estaba utilizando), es una limitación del propio Aginity.

Utilizando la alternativa mencionada en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-to-cluster.html) de Redshift (SQL Workbench/J), al lanzar el mismo comando no hay ningún problema:

`select * from pg_user`

```
usename usesysid usecreatedb usesuper usecatupd passwd   valuntil useconfig
adm_m   389      false       false    false     ********        
admin   100      true        true     false     ********          {TimeZone=CET}
```